# Code for number of negative edge cycle within a graph

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I am trying to compute number of negative  weights cycle in graph (weighted or unweighted ). But I do not find that how to compute this.
for example: if Directed weighted graph

```
nodes:[1,2,3,4,5] 

edges:[(1,2,w=1),(1,4,w=4),(2,3,w=2),(3,1,w=2),(3,5,w=1),(4,5,w=2),(5,4,w=7),(4,3,w=-6),(5,1,w=-7)]

cycles                 weight

[1, 4, 5, 1]            -1
[1, 4, 3, 5, 1]         -8
[1, 4, 3, 1]             0
[1, 2, 3, 5, 1]          -3
[1, 2, 3, 1]              5
[3, 5, 4, 3]              2
[4, 5, 4]                 9
```

Note :

```
 Negative Cycles: A negative cycle is a cycle in a weighted graph whose total weight is negative.
```

So, In this Graph have three negative cycles ([1, 4, 5, 1], [1, 4, 3, 5, 1],[1, 2, 3, 5, 1]) .
Can any one suggest me how to acchive number of negative cycle .

Comment: How are you calculating the weight of the cycle from the weights of the edges because looking at your edge weights and cycle weights it does not appear to be simply adding or multiplying.

Comment: Sorry sir, by mistake i print a wrong edge, correct edge list is below:                                                                                                             edges:[(1,2,w=1),(1,4,w=4),(2,3,w=2),(3,1,w=2),(3,5,w=1),(4,5,w=2),(5,4,w=7),(4,3,w=-6),(5,1,w=-7)]

Answer (score 0):

Networkx doesn't have a built-in function for this kind of problem. I suggest you to read [that paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166218X01002013/1-s2.0-S0166218X01002013-main.pdf?_tid=ff38562c-ec71-11e5-aebf-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1458241186_ee3e2b8353a9ee1d607ccea9e124184c) which may solve your problem. You will then have to code the algorithm by yourself in Networkx.